# Can we incrementally query a Hudi table based on a custom column (Spark SQL)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hudi

I'm trying to ingest historical data into a data catalog using Apache Hudi upsert. As the data is years and months old, I wanted to iterate each month, adding the historical date as a column to be queryable.
The problem is: incremental queries in Hudi takes _hoodie_commit_time as reference, and that commit time will not reflect the historical dates.

Is there a way to query Hudi tables using this custom date column as "instant" reference for incremental queries, maybe by adding this column data to the table metadata?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.